# Could anyone explain how the link is combined with the image in this site?

Tags: html

Normally, when we want to add some url link to a image, we simply put that image inside a  element.

However, I just found that in this page:
https://uk.burberry.com/mens-trench-coats/

The link of each coat is separated from the image. However, when the mouse is put on the coat image, we can still detect the link.

Could anyone explain how does this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link on the page you mentioned is `position: absolute;` and "moved" over the actuall image which is indeed placed in an other element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position